# Glen's power-law alternatives

Tags: models, glaciology

For glacier models, there exist alternatives to the Glen's power-law?

I searched on internet, but I have not found other alternatives.

Comment: Why are you looking for alternatives?

Comment: Please add more details, the answer will depend in the case you are considering. For instance if you have stress in all 3 axes you will need the generalized Glen-Nye flow law, and if you are considering heavily anisotropic ice there are some semiempirical formulas likes de ones of Thorsteinsson (2002). But in general the generalized Glen-Nye is enough, all the work usually goes to determine the creep parameter and the exponent, that can vary quite a lot.